# Predator-prey dynamical system. Find the vector $x_k$ for a certain $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems

> Consider a predator-pray model with the matrix $A= \begin{bmatrix}
>  0.5 & 0.6\\
>  -0.2 & 1.4 \end{bmatrix}$ ($A$ is the population distribution) and the initial state is $\vec{x}_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 10 \end{bmatrix}$.
> Find the vector $\vec{x}_k$ for $k = 10$.

How can I find $\vec{x}_{k=10}$? And could I find $\vec{x}_{k=11}$ from $\vec{x}_{k=10}$?

Comment: $x_1=A x_0$, $x_2=A x_1=A^2 x_0$. Continue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute force way is simply to multiply it out; you need $A^{10}$, so calculate $A^2$, then $A^4$, then $A^8$, then multiply by $A^2$.

Another way is to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix. If you can diagonalize A, finding its powers is easy.

If $A = PDP^{-1},$ then $A^{10} = PD^{10}P^{-1}$.